# Load iframe Inside Modal on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I'm building a retail website using Bootstrap. For the products there is a thumbnail with a "More Info" button that loads a modal. Inside of the modals is an iframe with more information for the bike. When I load the page it loads every iframe (about 60). I'm trying to figure out how to load the iframe (var bike_modal_descriptions_giant) when the appropriate button is clicked.

I have the site up for testing here: [Site](https://kelvinfox.com/work/road.html)

I'm using a javascript loop to populate the thumbnails.
[Screenshot of thumbnails.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvVj1.jpg)

Script that reads from other file to populate thumbnails, just changed for each brand:

```
<script>
for (i = 0; i < num_items_giant; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('catalogue').innerHTML += '<div class="row">';
    }
    document.getElementById('catalogue').innerHTML += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">'
        + '<div class="thumbnail">'
        + '<img src=' + bike_pics_giant[i] + '>'
        + '<div class="caption">'
        + '<h3>' + bike_titles_giant[i] + '</h3>'
        + '<p>' + bike_descriptions_giant[i] + '</p>'
        + '<p><button onclick="" type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-giant' + i + '">More Info</button></p>'
        + '<div class="modal fade" id="modal-giant' + i + '" role="dialog">'
        + '<div class="modal-dialog">'
        //<!-- Modal content-->
        + '<div class="modal-content">'
        + '<div class="modal-header">'
        + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>'
        + '<h4 class="modal-title">' + bike_titles_giant[i] + '</h4>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="modal-body">'
        + '<p>' + bike_modal_descriptions_giant[i] + '</p>'
        + '</div>'
        + '<div class="modal-footer">'
        + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>'
        + '</div>';
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('catalogue').innerHTML += '</div>';
    }
}
</script>
```

Modal Script:

```
<script>
/* Giant */
for (i = 0; i < num_items_giant; i++) {
    setupButton("btn-giant" + i, "modal-giant" + i);
}

/* Liv */
for (i = 0; i < num_items_liv; i++) {
    setupButton("btn-liv" + i, "modal-liv" + i);
}

function setupButton(button, modal){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#" + button).click(function(){
            $("#" + modal).modal();
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Truncated version of modal content file. Each section is an array and each row creates a new thumbnail:

```
var num_items_giant = 38;
var bike_pics_giant = ["pictures/bikes/2016/road/Propel/Propel-Adv-SL-0/Propel-Advanced-SL-0-Comp.jpg",
             "pictures/bikes/2016/road/Propel/Propel-Adv-SL-Team/Propel-Adv-SL-Team.jpg"];
var bike_titles_giant = ["Giant Propel Advanced SL 0",
               "Giant Propel Advanced SL Team"];
var bike_descriptions_giant = ["This pro peleton standout is the pinnacle of aero road. A killer in the sprints, with sublime overall ride quality.<br><strong>$9000</strong>",
                     "This pro peleton standout is the pinnacle of aero road. A killer in the sprints, with sublime overall ride quality.<br><strong>$6900</strong>";
var bike_modal_descriptions_giant = ["<iframe style=\"border:none\" width=\"710\" height=\"700\" src=\"https://www.giantretailacademy.com/go/?c=US&axid=600043\"></iframe>",
                            "<iframe style=\"border:none\" width=\"710\" height=\"700\" src=\"https://www.giantretailacademy.com/go/?c=US&axid=615001\"></iframe>";
```

Comment: You can set the source of the iframe when the button is clicked, or you can add the iframe html dynamically with javascript.

Comment: I already use a for loop to pull the information from another file and populate the page. My problem is the the "More Info" button loads the modal which has an iframe in it.